# Can I use a LambdaExpression type for MVC's HTML helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, expression, html-helper

I am trying to use reflection to auto-generate a view.  `Html.DisplayFor` and some of the other helpers take `Expression<Func<,>>` which derives from `LambdaExpression`.  Seemed like I'd be able to manually generate my own lambda and then pass that in, but it's throwing this error:

> The type arguments for method 'DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Here's my markup:

```
<tr>
    @foreach (var pi in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ExpressionHelpers.GetPropertyGetterLambda(pi))
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```

I am pretty sure what's happening is that `.DisplayFor` requires generic type arguments to infer the types for `Func<TModel, TValue>`, but I am using `LambdaExpression` which is hiding the types.

It seems like the only way to do what I want is to build/compile an expression that actually calls `.DisplayFor` using type-safe arguments, but that seems overly complicated.

Is there another way to achieve my goal or would I be better off just outputting the results directly to the HTML rather than calling the helpers?

Edit:  Per request, here's the code for `GetPropertyGetterLambda`:

```
public static LambdaExpression GetPropertyGetterLambda(PropertyInfo pi, BindingTypeSafety TypeSafety)
{
    if (pi.CanRead)
    {
        ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(TypeSafety.HasFlag(BindingTypeSafety.TypeSafeEntity) ?
            pi.ReflectedType : typeof(object));
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(GetPropertyReadExpression(entityParameter, pi, TypeSafety), entityParameter);
        return lambda;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show that method implementation?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Updated

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution for this that I recommend first. Change your for loop to an `DisplayForModel` call:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

That will render out all the properties, using `DisplayFor` internally. You can modify this by modifying the `Object.cshtml` in the `DisplayTemplates` folder (either in the `Views` folder your are working in, or in the `Shared` folder to apply globally).

If that is insufficient, or you really really want to use `LambdaExpression`, here is an alternative. It will require you adding a `DisplayFor<TModel>(LambdaExpression expression)` extension method. It would be something like (note that I haven't actually tested this, but this is close to what is needed):

```
    public static IHtmlString DisplayFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        var wrapperClass = typeof(DisplayExtensions);
        ///find matching DisplayFor<TModel, TProperty> method
        var matchingMethod = wrapperClass.GetMethods()
            .Single( c => c.IsStatic 
                && c.Name == "DisplayFor"
                && c.GetGenericArguments(  ).Count() == 2 
                && c.GetParameters(  ).Count() == 2 //overloads don't have same # of parameters. This should be sufficient.
                ).MakeGenericMethod( typeof(TModel), expression.ReturnType ); //Make generic type from the TModel and the Return Type

        //invoke the method. The result is a IHtmlString already, so just cast.
        return (IHtmlString) matchingMethod.Invoke( null, new Object[] { helper, expression } );
    }
```

Comment: Your second solution is basically what I was going to fall back on, but using reflection to generate a delegate at runtime with expression trees.  I don't think he first will work in my case, but good to know about it.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Why do you think the first will not work?